# Retrieve a list of all attributes in ldap3 (python3-ldap)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap3

Server is not returning same number of attributes for python-ldap and ldap3 Libraries.

The missing attributes are the one that I have to perform some operations.

This is the sample of the search query I used for ldap3:

```
from ldap3 import Server,Connection,ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES,ALL,SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE,SUBTREE

host = something1
user = something2
password = something3
baseDn = something4
search_filter = "(uid=something5)"

server = Server(host, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server,user, password,auto_bind=True,check_names=True)
conn.search(baseDn,search_filter, search_scope=SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE, attributes=['*'])

entry = conn.entries
print(json.loads(entry[0].entry_to_json()))
```

Search query used with python-ldap:

```
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
## retrieve all attributes 
retrieveAttributes = None
ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDn, searchScope, searchFilter,   retrieveAttributes)
result_set = []
while 1:
    result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
    if (result_data == []):
        break
    else:
        ## you could do whatever you want with the individual entry
        ## The appending to list is just for illustration.
        if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
            result_set.append(result_data)

print json.loads(result_set)
```

If someone can post, is there any way to retrieve all the attributes that are available for given query in ldap3.

Comment: It might be an issue with the server's implementation of LDAP, but for me, `attributes = ['*']` worked in getting all the attributes back using ldap3.

This is used against under Active Directory.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the Reader class, you can find allowedAttributes and allowedAttributesEffective:

```
from ldap3 import Server,Connection,Reader,ObjectDef

host = something1
user = something2
password = something3
baseDn = something4
search_filter = "(uid=something5)"

server = Server(host, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server,user, password,auto_bind=True,check_names=True)
inetorgperson = ObjectDef(['person','user'], conn)
reader = Reader(conn,inetorgperson,baseDn,search_filter)

reader.search()

>>> len(reader[0].allowedAttributes)
741
>>> len(reader[0].allowedAttributesEffective)
620
```